# Why does running this flask code gives an error?

Tags: python, flask

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXN9f.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80djc.png)
So, today I learned some absolute basic tutorials in Flask. After that I decide to make a simple program.
I saw some youtube tutorials regarding that.
First I made a virtual environment in my code editor(**VS Code**).
Then I activated the Scripts and Environment.
After that I installed flask in the virtual environment.
After that I typed the code which you can see in the file attached by me.
Then when I tried to get output of the code I got an error.

I expected that I would get a DNS Server.
If you know the solution of my problem please help

I got the following error:
**Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'. Use 'app:name' to specify one.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell flask where to find the app `python -m flask --app app run` with the argument to the `--app` flag being the name of the file without the extension you intend to run (In your case the file is named `app.py` so you would pass `app` as the argument)  [More information](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/)

Comment: python -m flask --app app run                          So I just written this code in my terminal But then also I am getting same error and thankyou for your answer

Comment: Try running `env FLASK_APP=app.py python -m flask run`

Comment: Sorry, but this solution did not helped. Now I am  getting this error   -                                                   **env : The term 'env' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a   
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ env FLASK_APP=your_app.py python -m flask run
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (env:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**